# active admin has_one duplication inside the select form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, activeadmin, has-one

The input of my active admin code gives me selection of all the addresses duplicated
I want the addresses without any duplication inside the select form [image]

in case new

```
  <%= form_for @case,:url => {:action => :create, :id => @user.id} do |f| %>
    Address:<br>
    <%= f.select :address, options_for_select(@user.addresses.all.pluck(:name,:id), @case.address&.id) %><br><br><br>
      Patient First Name:<%= f.text_field :pt_first_name, class: "textbox" ,required: "required" ,placeholder: "Patient Name"%>
      Patient Last Name:<%= f.text_field :pt_last_name, class: "textbox" ,required: "required" ,placeholder: "Patient Name"%>
<% end %>
```

in active admin case.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Case do
permit_params  :user_id, :product_ids,:step_ids  , :pt_first_name,:pt_last_name, 
:date_received, :due_date, :shade, :mould, :upper_lower,:invoice,:implant_brand, :implant_quantity,address_attributes: [ :name]

    form do |f|
            f.inputs do
                f.input :user
                f.inputs "address", for: [:address, f.object.address || Address.new] do |meta_form|
                meta_form.input :name, :as => :select, :collection => Address.order(name: :desc).collect {|address| [address.name, address.id] }
            end
             
            f.input :pt_first_name
            f.input :pt_last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `distinct` .. have a look [here for clear explanation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct)

So, this line:

```
<%= f.select :address, options_for_select(@user.addresses.all.pluck(:name,:id), @case.address&.id) %><br><br><br>
```

Should be like this:

```
<%= f.select :address, options_for_select(@user.addresses.distinct.pluck(:name,:id), @case.address&.id) %><br><br><br>
```

Also note that `@user.addresses.all` is the same as `@user.addresses`

Comment: Hi Khaled, I’m talking about active admin code. The one you wrote is working already

Comment: This one               f.inputs "address", for: [:address, f.object.address || Address.new] do |meta_form|

                meta_form.input :name, :as => :select, :collection => Address.order(name: :desc).collect {|address| [address.name, address.id] }

Comment: I guess it would be close to what I wrote as well.
Address.order(name: :desc).distinct.collect

Comment: No it's not working. the duplication is so weird